# If data available get that data, if Atribute Error write except message

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi there i using beautiful soup to scrap website and then get some information that i need.
I have the problem when not all item in that website have same information, so i can get Attribution Error.

so when i can get the data, scrap that data and then get the image.
To easy what i mean, i make illustration code like this.

```
informationdata=("We can get the data information")
if informationdata():
  try:
    imagedata=("After get the information we can get image")
  except:
    exceptdata=("If data information get Atribute Error, we write something like this")    
print(informationdata)
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC7am.jpg)

i hope i can get like this when data information available :

[(We can get the data information),(After get the information we can get image)]

but if data not available or Attribute Error :
[(If data information get Attribute Error, we write something like this)]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your informationdata() remove the parenthesis.